# Using Html.ActionLink for generating Jquery UI tab links

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, actionlink

I'm using Jquery UI tabs where I'm attempting to load data via ajax. The links are generated programmatically.

```
string LinkID = "";

<ul>
 @foreach (MyItem item in Model.ItemList)
 {
   <li>
    LinkID = "subcat" + ViewBag.F_ID + "-tabs-item" + item.ID + "-link";
    @Html.ActionLink( item.Name,           //Link Text
                     "GetItem",            //Action Name
                     "Items",              //Controller Name
                      //Route Values
                      new { C_ID = ViewBag.C_ID, D_ID = ViewBag.D_ID, E_ID = ViewBag.E_ID, F_ID = ViewBag.F_ID, G_ID = ViewBag.G_ID, Item_ID = item.ID }, 
                      //HTML Attributes
                      new { id = LinkID, @class = "ItemLoadViaAjax", title = item.Name })
   </li>   
  }
 </ul>
```

---

The anchor element that gets generated:

```
  <a class="ItemLoadViaAjax" 
     href="#Cadbury_Eclairs" 
     id="subcat11-tabs-item9-link" 
     title="Cadbury Eclairs">
     Cadbury Eclairs
  </a>
```

The `href` value is the same as that of the `title`, instead of the URL generated from ActionLink.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Shouldnt you have to pass a href attribute to the htmlAttributes parameter of ActionLink?

Comment: @garfbradaz: As per my understanding, the `href` value is generated by `Html.ActionLink`. See [Understanding HTML Helpers](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx) and [this W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try below. think you are passing values for routevalues parameter

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: item.Name, actionName: "GetItem", 
                  controllerName: "Items", 
                  RouteValues: new { C_ID = ViewBag.C_ID, D_ID = ViewBag.D_ID, E_ID =  ViewBag.E_ID, F_ID = ViewBag.F_ID, G_ID = ViewBag.G_ID, Item_ID = item.ID }
                  htmlAttributes: new { id = LinkID, @class = "ItemLoadViaAjax", title = item.Name },
routeValues: null)
```

Working on ASPX Views.

```
<a class="ItemLoadViaAjax" href="/TRS/ControllerName/ActionName.aspx?C_ID=ViewBag.C_ID&amp;D_ID=ViewBag.D_ID&amp;E_ID=ViewBag.E_ID&amp;F_ID=ViewBag.F_ID&amp;G_ID=ViewBag.G_ID&amp;Item_ID=item.ID" id="LinkID" title="item.Name">LinkText</a>
```

Comment: I need to pass routeValues as well as htmlAttributes

Comment: Which  are your route values?

Comment: href should not be passed. I'm using Html ActionLink.

Comment: Regarding your question about route values, please see the code  - I've added comments.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the reason why it's happening, but I replaced `Html.ActionLink` with a `<a href..>` statement with `href` value set to a div's ID and using the "onclick" function to call another Javascript function to do the ajax post.